# Environment variable for iPhoneOS SDK directory

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a script which builds a project from a command line. It needs path like `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOSX.Y[.Z].sdk`.

The problem is that once X,Y and Z change on build machine, everything brakes.
Is there something like `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS%iPhoneOSver%.sdk`?

`set | grep iPhoneOS` did not show any clue

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an older unanswered question, but I just threw together a script since I was running into the same issue. Hope this helps you too.  :-)

https://gist.github.com/1572524

Comment: Did you have any success with Xcode4 on Lion? I have a pretty recent/clean mac with XCode installed from AppStore, and `xcode-select -print-path` does not work. It reports `xcode-select: Error: No Xcode folder is set. Run xcode-select -switch <xcode_folder_path> to set the path to the Xcode folder.`